# Function is not accessed

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my code:

```
self.msg_entry = Entry(bottom_label, bg="#2C3E50", fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=FONT)
self.msg_entry.place(relwidth=0.74, relheight=0.06, rely=0.008, relx=0.011)
self.msg_entry.focus()
self.msg_entry.bind("<Return>", self._on_enter_pressed)
  
def _on_enter_pressed(self, event):
  msg = self.msg_entry.get()
  self._insert_message(msg, "You")
```

on hovering on on_enter_pressed function, it's showing function is not accessed and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "GUI.py", line 91, in <module>
        app = ChatApplication()
      File "GUI.py", line 15, in __init__
        self._setup_main_window()
      File "GUI.py", line 76, in _setup_main_window
        self.msg_entry.bind("<Return>", self._on_enter_pressed)
    AttributeError: 'ChatApplication' object has no attribute '_on_enter_pressed'
```

(I'm using tkinter in python to implement GUI.)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this inside of a class `__init__`? Are you showing us the correct indentation? The fact that you're initializing things on `self` makes me think this is in `__init__`, but then you define what looks to be an attempt at an instance method.

Comment: It looks like your code is scoped within a class, but you didn't include that in your example. Python does not hoist methods of classes. You will need to bind your function after you define _on_enter_pressed. Move the top four lines below your func or put them in the `__init__` dunder method

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have `def _on_enter_pressed` inside other function (probably `__init__`) so it is NOT class function and you can't use `self._on_enter_pressed` but `_on_enter_pressed`. OR change indentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong indentations - `_on_enter_pressed` has to be outside `__init__`

```
def __init__(self):
    # ... code ..

    self.msg_entry = Entry(bottom_label, bg="#2C3E50", fg=TEXT_COLOR,  font=FONT)
    self.msg_entry.place(relwidth=0.74, relheight=0.06, rely=0.008,  relx=0.011)
    self.msg_entry.focus()
    self.msg_entry.bind("<Return>", self._on_enter_pressed)
  
# outside `__init__`

def _on_enter_pressed(self, event):
    msg = self.msg_entry.get()
    self._insert_message(msg, "You")
```